# Wordpress Re-Write Rule Does Not Work With "name" But Works With "p"

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

If I set up a Wodpress re-write rule like so:

```php
function lf_blog_add_rewrites()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^blog/([^/]+)$',
        'index.php?name=somepost-slug',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'lf_blog_add_rewrites' );
```

I get a 404 page.

The following works perfectly, however...

```php
function lf_blog_add_rewrites()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^blog/([^/]+)$',
        'index.php?p=4567',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'lf_blog_add_rewrites' );
```

I am trying to link to get "/blog/slug-of-post' to link to the page. What might I be doing wrong?

Lastly, if this is not possible for some reason, I can see that: index.php?name=some-slug seems to do a 301 re-direct to the right place. So how can I set up a URL re-write without breaking WP .htaccess rewrite rules?

Comment: because in wordpress, the default query for post is p, name does not exist.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial - Sorry did not understand this. How should I query based on a post slug then?

Comment: why don't u use permalink in your wordpress settings?

Comment: I have custom post types. I don't want their URLs to get "/blog" slug before all of them. @so

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial - According to this, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#search-parameters I can query using the name paramter